# VSTS Project Hierarchy

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to know about structuring a team / project with in VSTS.
What is the differences between project and team within VSTS ?

For example, I have this example scenario.
There is a e-commerce development. It has Web, Mobile, and Recommendation Engine (Multi Tenant Project, this Reco Engine will be used for another web / platform).
There are some role like backend, frontend, UI/UX, DevOps/Infra, and manager.

How should I implement project hierarchy on VSTS ?
Project -> Teams

Idea 1:

> Web Project -> Backend, FrontEnd, UI/UX, DevOps
>
> Mobile Project -> Backend, FrontEnd, UI/UX, DevOps
>
> Reco Engine -> Backend, FrontEnd, UI/UX, DevOps

Idea 2:

> E-commerce -> Web Team, Mobile Team, Backend Team, Infra Team
>
> Reco Engine -> Main team

Or is there any Idea how can I structure my VSTS ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the relations between project and team is: **a VSTS project can contain multiple teams**.

And how to manage project with teams in VSTS is based on the relations among the projects/modules (Web, Mobile and Recommendation Engine) and they're roles.

And since the modules (Web, Mobile and Recommendation Engine) are the parts of the E-commerce, you should manage them **in the same VSTS project with different repositories** (or same repo with different branches).

For the teams, you can create by the situation you meet as below:

- If developers for a role are developer across the modules. Such as developers for BackEnd are develop for all the Web, Mobile and Recommendation Engine projects, then you can create teams like `Backend`, `FrontEnd`, `UI/UX`, `DevOps` etc.
- If If developers for a role are different from different projects. Such as developers for BackEnd of the Web project are different from the developers for the BackEnd of the Mobile project, then you should create teams like `BackEnd_Web`, `BackEnd_Mobile` etc.

So the structure of the VSTS project should look like:

```
VSTS project        repo                                 team
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              |     Web           | Backend_Web, FrontEnd_Web, UI/UX_Web, DevOps_Web
E-commerce    |     Mobile        | Backend_Mobile, FrontEnd_Mobile, UI/UX_Mobile, DevOps_Mobile
              |     Reco Engine   | Backend_Reco, FrontEnd_Reco, UI/UX_Reco, DevOps_Reco
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your amazing explanation of this hierarchy. Maybe, our condition is match with your first situation that a developers may work across the module.

I was reading about areas, what is it ? is it different from team ?

Comment: Area is a field for work items, it can help you to group work items by different teams (quite different from team). Such as you can create an area path `projectname\Backend`, so all the work items related to Backend can be specifies with the area path `projectname\Backend`. And you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts for work item area.